# "Head start" for "advantage". Then what is for "disadvantage"?

Tags: synonyms, slang, informal-language, idiom-request, offensive-language

There are many synonyms, slang expressions, and idioms that refers to or almost to "advantage." For example, well as I said, a head start refers to an advantage.

However there are rarely a few words that is for "**dis**advantage." Here are from *Thesaurus.com*:

- detriment
- **harm**
- prejudice
- **damage**
- deprivation
- disservice
- **injury**

**bolded**: common

So I am looking for a *cool* idiom for "disadvantage". It should sound:

- **cool** (duh)
- informal (well, I said "cool")
- not necessarily 2+ words
- spoken widely in the U.S. (but British and other dialects are welcome, too) ***or***
- be an idiom that everyone (native speakers) knows but is possibly offensive for some people (or something that I should bear in mind in case I come across it and use it without knowing and running into a problem. For example, I am not supposed to ever say the n-word in my entire life. Like that.)

I'm fine with seeing foul language like "grab them with the... *ahem*" without being censored or warning, if you need it.

Comment: *a native speaker (inside of the brackets). Doing that kind of correction here so just anybody swinging by can clearly see that EVERY is a SINGULAR thing and if they were wrong, they can correct their mistakes too.

Comment: We have the answer in EL&U http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231733/is-there-any-idiom-which-is-exactly-opposite-of-head-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'cool' is quite a subjective term, and without any context to go on, it's really quite difficult to say whether a particular idiom or synonym will fit the context of the sentence you want to drop it into.

There are many words and expressions that can be used to describe a disadvantage - just off the top of my head, the following ones come to mind, but there are many more.

- held back
- hamstrung
- handicap
- hampered
- stumbling block
- downside

> The only thing that **held** Joe **back** from joining the swim team was lack of transportation.
>
> The company claims it is being **hamstrung** by government regulations.
>
> The basketball player's small size did not **handicap** him in the least.
>
> The project was **hampered** by budget restraints.
>
> My plans to take over the world hit a **stumbling block**.
>
> The **downside** of living in the country is, of course, the long commute to work.

If you'd like something more specific, then you may wish to edit your question to include a sentence or paragraph to set the tone of what you are looking for.